# Why object be deleted without obvious code?

Tags: c++, qt, object

In qt, I use tablewidget to store 100 rows. At first, I new tableWidgetItems to fill the rows.
As it runs, I set the items' propertities and no longer 'new'.
But I find after I use *'ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(index);'*, and later set back to 100, the code *"ui->tableWidget->item(index, 0)->setText(...);"* will crash the program. That's so bad!!! ;(
I debugged and find the new index > index set as row count before 'setting back to 100'.

**Did the system delete the table items automatically when I set smaller row count???**

I fear about this so much because even my code cannot determine the lifetime of the objects I created... Does anyone know how to keep them 'alive' after setting row count?(otherwise, I have to new them...).
I really appreciate it you take the patience to read my poor ELis:)

new:

```
//TABLE
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(100);
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)//new
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, 0 , new QTableWidgetItem(""));//time
        ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, 1 , new QTableWidgetItem(""));//name
        ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, 2 , new QTableWidgetItem(""));//BITS
    }
```

---

Related code lines only:

```
   {
    int  index = 0;
    for(int queue_i = size_1; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--)
    {


        if(logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(3) == "0" ||   logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(3) == "2")continue;


        QStringList BITList = bits2Hexs(queue_i);


     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 0)->setText(logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(0));//time
     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 1)->setText(logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(1));//name
     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 2)->setText(BITList.join(""));//BITS

        if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);
        index++;
    }

        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(index);//set row count to be 30 more or less
    }
```

Another function:

```
    {

        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(100);//back to be 100 again


        for(int queue_i = size_1, index = 0; queue_i >= 0; queue_i--, index++)
        {

            QStringList BITList = bits2Hexs(queue_i);
     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 0)->setText(logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(0));//time
     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 1)->setText(logDisplayQueue.at(queue_i).at(1));//name
     ui->tableWidget->item(index, 2)->setText(BITList.join(""));//BITS
//In debugging, when index reches the value of old row-count, "->setText" crashes the    //program.


            if(queue_i == oldRowItemNo)ui->tableWidget->selectRow(index);
        }

    }
```

*When running, it returns message like 'instruction 0x00421727 refers to 0x00000000 memory, the memory cannot be 'read''*

**if I comment off this line:
'ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(index);//set row count to be 30 more or less', it runs well without crash and rows after index-referred-row show the same data as before.**

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the table widget ?

Comment: IIRC, Qt types manage the lifetime of every pointer they take as a child-widget.

Comment: I'm not a Qt person, but I don't think this has to do with the objects being deleted, the table simply doesn't remember the objects it previously referenced.

Comment: But if I comment off this line: **'ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(index);//set row count to be 30 more or less'**, it runs well without crash. :) @enobayram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setRowCount` ensures that the table holds exactly that many rows. If you had more rows than `index` before, those rows are gone (deleted).

If you want to temporarily hide rows, you should probably use [`hideRow(int)`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtableview.html#hideRow)/`showRow` rather than resetting the row count.